# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 get Company Name

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there any way to get the current company name when on a transaction entry page? Either some session object, global object, or some sort. Kind of like how you can get the user name from the runtime module? I see country name, but cannot seem to get the company name. Using a client script for this.

How I get the user name:

runtime.getCurrentUser().name

thank you

Here is the working code now, but trying to figure a way to get this on a client script. Possible to pass this value?

```
    var companyInfo = config.load({
        type: config.Type.COMPANY_INFORMATION
    });
    
    var compname = companyInfo.getValue({
        fieldId: 'companyname'
    });
    
    log.debug(compname);
    
    scriptContext.form.addButton({
        id: "custpage_mybutton",
        label: "View Documents",
        functionName: "onButtonClick"
    });
    scriptContext.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/dl_cs_vendorbill.js";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server side scripts you can do this:

```js
require(['N/config'], config=>{
   const info = config.load({type:config.Type.COMPANY_INFORMATION});
    log.debug({title:'Current company Info', details:info.getValue({fieldId:'companyname'}));
});
```

For a client script you could use that code in a paired user event script.
In the before phase of the UE you'd do the lookup and then add a hidden field to the form with the company name as a value. Your client script can then look that up like any normal `getValue`

Comment: Thanks again bknights, is there any way we can do this on client script button press function? This works on my user event script. Or is there a way I can pass this to the client script?

Comment: added a suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Likely overkill, but you could also use a restlet and make requests to it from client script if this is something you would want to use in multiple places.

Comment: Thank you bknights again! Works like a charm. I appreciate your help. You're a lifesaver. And thank you Steffen as well, yes that would be a bit overkill for my scenario but good to know and I appreciate your suggestion too.